# proxy classes of web-service using WSDL

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am getting the following exception whenever trying to create proxy classes using WSDL.

Few observations :-

1) My WSDL points out/imports following xsd **http://200.123.23.196:9090**/TOOLBOX/WSDL/temp/temparature.xsd.
If i use the tempratue.xsd in wsdl from above URL, It always fails and throws
following exception in eclipse.

2) If i try to acess the same XSD from diffrent server it works properly and creates
  proxy classes (temparature.xsd is available on diffrent servers).

3)Why same XSD is behaving dieffrently on diffrent servers.

4)One more observation :- when i put this url in browser **http://200.123.23.196:9090**/TOOLBOX/WSDL/temp/temparature.xsd i can not see the content of xsd in browser directly. Instead using other URL i can see the content directly.

IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  WSDLException (at /definitions/types/schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'http://200.123.23.196:9090/TOOLBOX/WSDL/temp/temparature.xsd', relative to 'file:/D:/workspaces/globice/LAS/xsd/my_ice.wsdl'.: no content-type: java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentHandler(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:516)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)

Waiting for replies :)

Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
```

suggest that the server is not setting the content-type header to **application/xml** or **text/xml** in response to 'http://200.123.23.196:9090/TOOLBOX/WSDL/temp/temparature.xsd'.

Can you verify that?